# Mongoose: Populate all objects in array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am developing a blog application
I have such a model for posts

```
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    text: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    tags: {
      type: Array,
      default: [],
    },
    viewsCount: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: true,
    },
    commentary: {// Will store comment objects
      type: Array,
      default: [],
    },
    imageUrl: String, 
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

There is also a model for comments

```
const CommentarySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  post: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Post",
    required: true,
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true,
  },
});
```

Here is the method by which I add comments

```
export const createCommentary = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const postId = req.params.id;

    const doc = new Commentary({
      text: req.body.text,
      post: postId,
      user: req.userId,
    });
    const comment = await doc.save();

    await PostModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        _id: postId,
      },
      {
        $push: { commentary: comment },
      }
    );

    res.json({ success: true });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

How do I make a populate("user") for all comments that are stored in the array?

```
export const getOne = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const postId = req.params.id;

    const doc = await PostModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        _id: postId,
      },
      {
        $inc: { viewsCount: 1 },
      },
      { returnDocument: "after" }
    ).populate("user").populate("commentary.user");
    
    if (!doc) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Can not res post" });
    }

    res.json(doc);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({
      message: "Can not find post",
    });
  }
};
```

Sorry for my bad english)
How do I make a populate("user") for all comments that are stored in the array?
Maybe i need to store in Posts.commentary array id for comment?
Please help

I tried:

```
.populate("user").populate("commentary.user");
// and
const arrOfPromises = doc.commentary.map((comment) =>
        comment.populate("user")
      );
      await Promise.all(arrOfPromises);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This modification should work:

```js
const doc = await PostModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: postId,},
      {
        $inc: { viewsCount: 1 },
      },
      { new: true }
      ).populate({
         path: 'user', model: UserModel
      }).populate({
         path: 'commentary.user', model: UserModel 
      });
```

You will notice I have added the `{ new: true }` option because:

> You should set the new option to true to return the document after update was applied.

Depending on your design, it is often the case that you need to specify the `path` and `model` properties inside the populate so I have included them for you. Just switch `UserModel` with the actual name of your models.

Comment: You just saved me, thank you so much
I'm sorry for answering so late

Comment: @NikiLee you're welcome. Good luck with your project.